# UI-Automation testing of obfuscated (WPF-) applications

Tags: wpf, obfuscation, ui-automation, ranorex

I was wondering, how difficult it is to run UI-Tests, if the code has been obfuscated (especially regarding WPF-Applications when using testing frameworks that access automation properties of the application and arent image-based like e.g. Ranorex, TestStudio, TestComplete, Squish,...).

I can only find few informations about this, which imply, that testing should always be done before the code is being obfuscated, but not precisely why.

One might argue however, that tests should be run on the version that´s actually being shipped to the customer. Also if we´re using 3rd-Party components as part of our SW, we might not have the luxury of using a not-obfuscated version.

As far as I understand UI-Automation, the goal is to expose relevant properties of the application, so that they can be used not just by testing-frameworks, but also screen-readers and the like.
Therefore I can´t quite understand why there might be problems once the code is being obfuscated. The obfuscation itself shouldn´t influence the number of exposed properties at all or does it?

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for the others, but Ranorex relies on UIA (UIAutomation), an automation and accessibility framework, to automate WPF apps.

UIA is almost never affected by obfuscation. Also keep in mind that most obfuscation tools avoid obfuscating public members of public classes, which is what most UI controls use.

The only exceptions are rare cases in which you explicitly configure the obfuscation tool to obfuscate strings that might affect UIA, such as the `AutomationProperties` attached properties.

Another rather rare exception might have to do with reflection. If you use reflection (usually a bad idea, but sometimes unavoidable) to activate less reachable areas of your app, then obfuscation might pose a problem. This problem is easily solved by adding a few exceptions to the obfuscation tool, or running the tests before obfuscation.

Theoretically, it shouldn't matter whether you test the app before or after it's been obfuscated because obfuscation should *theoretically* not have any effect on the app's logic. In practice, there are some differences and this might affect your tests, though very rarely. Obfuscated apps tend to be a bit faster, and sometimes obfuscation mangles unexpected or unplanned code elements. So you have to ask yourself whether you want to perform UI automation on the app the users will actually get and catch obfuscation issues that might only affect UI automation, or test the app before obfuscation to ensure the app's behavior is correct regardless of whatever additional build and deployment steps might be waiting in the pipeline. Obviously, you'll have to deal with the possible repercussions of whichever approach you choose.

Another consideration for running the tests before obfuscation is that if application errors are encountered while running the tests, developers will have an easier time debugging them. However, if the programmers know how to debug obfuscated symbols (with code maps or the like), then this consideration is mostly moot.